# JavaFX EventHandler не меняет значение полей

Tags: java, javafx, события

Есть два класса. Application:

```
public class MainWindowApplication extends Application {

    MainWindowController mwc = new MainWindowController();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainWindowApplication.class.getResource("main-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(mwc);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, mwc);
        stage.setTitle("Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

и Controller:

```
public class MainWindowController implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

private boolean moveUp;
private boolean moveDown;
private boolean moveRight;
private boolean moveLeft;

public void initialize() {
    init();
    start();
}

void start() {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), ev -> {
        move();
        repaint();
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
    System.out.println(moveUp);
}

public void init() {
    //TODO
}

public void move() {
    if (moveUp) {
        System.out.println("MOVE UP");
    }
    if (moveDown) {
        System.out.println("MOVE DOWN");
    }
    if (moveLeft) {
        System.out.println("MOVE LEFT");
    }
    if (moveRight) {
        System.out.println("MOVE RIGHT");
    }
}

public void repaint(){
    //TODO
}

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent KeyEvent) {
    switch (KeyEvent.getCode()) {
        case UP:
            System.out.println("UP");
            moveUp = true;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            System.out.println("LEFT");
            moveLeft = true;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            System.out.println("RIGHT");
            moveRight = true;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            System.out.println("DOWN");
            moveDown = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Проблема в том, что EventHandler обрабатывает события не так, как мне нужно. При нажатии на кнопки клавиатуры, текстовые сообщения из метода *handle* выводятся в консоль, т.е нажатия передаются в программу, но значение boolean полей класса остаются неизменными (*false*), соответственно метод *move* не работает. Не могу понять где ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал *Enum* вместо boolean переменных

```
public enum Move {
UP,
DOWN,
LEFT,
RIGHT
}

public class MainWindowController implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

static Move move = Move.RIGHT;

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent KeyEvent) {
    if (KeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        System.out.println("UP");
        move = Move.UP;
    }
    if (KeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        System.out.println("DOWN");
        move = Move.DOWN;
    }
    if (KeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
        System.out.println("LEFT");
        move = Move.LEFT;
    }
    if (KeyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        System.out.println("RIGHT");
        move = Move.RIGHT;
    }
}
```

и проблема решилась. Почему не работал первоначальный вариант так и не понял.